# Are Stream.ReadAsync and Stream.WriteAsync supposed to alter the cursor position synchronously before returning or after the operation completes?

Tags: c#, stream, async-await, filestream, c#-5.0

I've been attempting to implement a `Stream` that supports `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync`, and given the spareseness of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx), I'm struggling to understand how to do so properly. Specifically, with respect to the stream's cursor position. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779526/sequential-asynchronous-reads-using-stream-beginread) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564621/synchronization-requirements-for-filestream-begin-endread-write) regarding the old `BeginRead` function. The documentation for that function seemed to indicate that `BeginRead` should not be called again until any pending asynchronous operations had completed.

Given that `BeginRead` is now <s>deprecated</s> [no longer recommended for new development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx) and `Stream` has likely been significantly altered to implement the new Async functions, things are once again unclear. (EDIT: Usually this kind of warning means that the new functions are implemented directly and the old functions call the new ones and are only still there for backwards compatibility, but that appears to not quite be the case here).

The `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` functions are defined such that they don't take the desired read/write stream position as their [Win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx) [counterparts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365748(v=vs.85).aspx) do (a very poor design choice in my opinion), but instead rely on the current position held by the stream implementation. That situation is fine if one of two conditions hold:

1. `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` must grab the current cursor position for use by the operation and update it as if the operation completed (or not update it at all) before they return the `Task`, or
2. No calls to `ReadAsync` or `WriteAsync` can be made until all previous async calls have been completed.

Outside of those two conditions, the caller can never be sure of the position the read or write will occur at because pending asynchronous operations could alter the position of the stream in between any `Seek` and call to `ReadAsync` or `WriteAsync`. Neither of these conditions is documented as a requirement, so I'm left to wonder how it's supposed to function.

My whitebox testing seems to indicate that at least for the `FileStream` version of `Stream`, the stream position updates asynchronously, which would seem to indicate that the second condition (only one pending operation allowed) is still the one that is required, but that seems like a serious limitation (it certainly precludes any kind of internal scatter-gather implementation).

Can anyone provide any kind of authoritative information as to whether the old `BeginRead` limitation still applies to `ReadAsync` or not?

Comment: I think the logic behind the design is that a stream is, by its very nature, not thread-safe; hence it doesn't make sense to access it while an asynchronous operation is in progress (just because the operation is asynchronous, allowing your code to gracefully wait on the stream read/write without blocking, does not mean it's a good idea to play with the stream from another thread while that operation is in progress).

Comment: Given that `ReadAsync` will read an unknown number of bytes, how could it possibly accurately update the position before the operation has completed?

Comment: Concurrent IOs, even if initiated sequentially, can result in the callback being called concurrently. That's a race condition for most stream implementations. So this is not allowed in general.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point. I was thinking mostly about FileStreams where it is always possible, but for most other streams you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone provide any kind of authoritative information as to whether the old `BeginRead` limitation still applies to `ReadAsync` or not?

The same limitations apply for `BeginRead` and `ReadAsync`.

The old APM methods haven't been deprecated. They are still fully supported and there's nothing wrong with using them. However, the `async` methods are considerably easier to use so the documentation suggests using them instead.

All these `async` "overloads" on these old classes usually do still consist of calling `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` or at most both options call a shared method (e.g. [`FileStream.BeginReadAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,b199fd3a2987ffa3,references)). I have never seen any code (in the framework or otherwise) that has APM wrapper methods over the `async` one.

Therefore, [calling `ReadAsync` will result in calling `BeginRead`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,81408d129d1e9739,references) so any limitation applies to both. Furthermore, since `Stream` isn't thread-safe and doesn't advertise as being concurrent-safe (which is slightly different) it's safe to assume you can't flood it with `async` requests concurrently.

Comment: In the absence of documentation, I'd wish ther was at least a comment somewhere in the source code indicating this restriction, but I suppose a 30 minutes of study of the raw source code will have to suffice. Thanks!

Comment: I did love this comment in that function on line 2023: `This code needs to be fixed.`